# Is there any way to make this code more efficient? because I want to solve a challenge on google's platform and it gives me Time Limited Exceeded

Tags: arrays, algorithm, list, sorting, dart

Here's the [problem](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/00000000000000cb/00000000000079cb)

> ### Trouble Sort
>
> The basic operation of the standard bubble sort algorithm is to examine a pair of adjacent numbers, and reverse that pair if the left number is larger than the right number. But our algorithm examines a group of three adjacent numbers, and if the leftmost number is larger than the rightmost number, it reverses that entire group.
>
> Because our algorithm is a "triplet bubble sort", we have named it Trouble Sort for short.
>
> For example, for L = 5 6 6 4 3, Trouble Sort would proceed as follows:
>
> - First pass:
>
>   - inspect 5 6 6, do nothing: 5 6 6 4 3
>   - inspect 6 6 4, see that 6 > 4, reverse the triplet: 5 4 6 6 3
>   - inspect 6 6 3, see that 6 > 3, reverse the triplet: 5 4 3 6 6
> - Second pass:
>
>   - inspect 5 4 3, see that 5 > 3, reverse the triplet: 3 4 5 6 6
>   - inspect 4 5 6, do nothing: 3 4 5 6 6
>   - inspect 5 6 6, do nothing: 3 4 5 6 6
> - Then the third pass inspects the three triplets and does nothing, so the algorithm terminates.
>
> It is possible that Trouble Sort does not correctly sort the list! Consider the list 8 9 7, for example.
>
> Given a list of N integers, determine whether Trouble Sort will successfully sort the list into non-decreasing order. 
>   If it will not, find the index (counting starting from 0) of the first sorting error after the algorithm has finished: 
>   that is, the first value that is larger than the value that comes directly after it when the algorithm is done.
>
> ### Input
>
> The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, **T**. **T** test cases follow. Each test case consists of two lines: one line with an integer **N**, the number of values in the list, and then another line with **N** integers **V<sub>i</sub>**, the list of values.
>
> ### Output
>
> For each test case, output one line containing `Case #x: y`, where `x` is the test case number (starting from 1) and `y` is `OK` if Trouble Sort correctly sorts the list, or the index (counting starting from 0) of the first sorting error, as described above.
>
> ### Sample
>
> ```
> Input      | Output
> -----------+-------------
> 2          |
> 5          |
> 5 6 8 4 3  |  Case #1: OK
> 3          |
> 8 9 7      |  Case #2: 1
> ```
>
> Sample Case #1 is similar to the first one described in the problem statement. Trouble Sort correctly sorts this list, so the answer is OK.
>
> Sample Case #2 is the second one described in the problem statement. Trouble Sort does not correctly sort this list, since it terminates with the list 7 9 8. The 9 is the first value in the list that is larger than the next value, so the index of the first sorting error is 1.

Test set 1
Like bubble sort, Trouble Sort has O(N2) time complexity; the proof is explained below. With N ≤ 100 for test set 1, we can run Trouble Sort to completion and simply iterate over the result list to find the first sorting error, if any (that is, a value that is greater than the value that follows it in the list).

Test set 2
Running O(N2) Trouble Sort to completion is too slow for N ≤ 105.

Instead, let's break down what Trouble Sort is doing at each step. Let's consider an input list of 6 elements. Trouble Sort makes the following comparisons on each pass through the array:

element 0 ↔ element 2
element 1 ↔ element 3
element 2 ↔ element 4
element 3 ↔ element 5
Regardless of the length of the list, this table illustrates the fundamental flaw in Trouble Sort: even-index elements are compared with other even-index elements, and odd-index elements are compared with other odd-index elements, but even-index and odd-index elements are never compared with each other! This means that Trouble Sort is just bubble sort run separately on the even-index elements and the odd-index elements, interleaving them into the output list. Trouble Sort is correct only if interleaving the two sub-lists (the even-index list and the odd-index list) happens to produce another sorted list. Since there are O(N) even-index and O(N) odd-index elements, and since bubble sort is O(N2), Trouble Sort is also O(N2).

To solve test set 2, we can can run our favorite O(N log N) sorting algorithm independently on the two sub-lists described above, interleave the sorted sub-lists, and then find the first sorting error as in our solution for test set 1.

What I already tried is to minimize the use of nested for's to reduce time complexity and I couldn't find another way to check if my array is sorted besides checking all the places and returning the index the sorting algorithm doesn't work

Here's the full code and I implement it correctly because when the first test case is given it gives the result, but then it exceeds the time that is 20 secs, idk if there's another solution to this.

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

Stream<String> readLine() => stdin
    .transform(utf8.decoder)
    .transform(const LineSplitter());

main() {
  String stringCase;
  //List<String> results =[];

  int numberOfCases = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  stdout.flush();
  // we read the input as google wants,
  BytesBuilder builder = new BytesBuilder();
  for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfCases; i++) {
      int size = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
      List<int> lint = new List(size);
      for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        int char = stdin.readByteSync();
        while (char >= 48 && char <= 57) {
          builder.addByte(char);
          char = stdin.readByteSync();
        }
        lint[j] = int.parse(String.fromCharCodes(builder.takeBytes()));
      }
      //print(lint);
      if(lint.length > 1 && lint.length <= math.pow(10, 9)){
   print("Case #${i}: ${separateArray(lint)}");
      stdout.flush();
  }

  }

  return 0;
}

separateArray(array){

  List<int> odds = new List((array.length / 2).floor());
  List<int> evens= new List(array.length - odds.length);

  int m, n;
  m = 0;
  n = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
    if(i%2==0){
     evens[n] = array[i];
     n++;
    }
    if(i%2!=0){
      odds[m] = array[i];
      m++;
    }
  }
  evens = evens..sort();
  odds = odds..sort();
  var j=0,k=0;
  for(var i=0; i<array.length-1;i++){
    if(i%2==0){
      if (evens[j] > odds[k]) {
          return i;
      }
      j++;
    }else{
      if (odds[k] > evens[j]) {
        return i;
      }
      k++; 
    }
  }
  return "OK";
}
```

Idk If you guys see anything I don't. I'd appreciate some help

Comment: You could fill the odd and even arrays more efficiently by just doing two loops, e.g. for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i+=2) even[n++]=array[i]; Same for odd, just start with i=1. You don't need modulo. Also the 2nd loop doesn't need modulo, you can use a boolean variable and switch it each iteration. Or go through odd and even separately again and return smaller error found, if any.

Comment: I don't know dart, aren't there any arrays? If the lists are linked lists and the code is not optimized somehow then evens[j] is O(n) instead of O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Assume an input of 10000 values, where Trouble Sort will give its first error at index 3. Then it was really not worth the effort to have sorted the whole array of 10000 values (twice 5000). It would have been enough to have identified the min and second-min values in both the odd and even series.

The common remedy for such situations, is the use of priority queues, e.g. min-heaps.

So, you could organise the odd and even series into min-heaps, and then start popping values from those until you detect a wrong order.

You could even implement those two heaps in-line (interwoven), without copying the odd/even values into new, dedicated arrays.

[Building a heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap) takes *O(n)* when done in buttom-up order and sifting down each subroot.

In the worst case, where Trouble Sort turns out to sort the array correctly, you would have spent *O(nlogn)* time in popping all values from the two heaps, which matches the time complexity you already had.

Comment: You should be able to solve it as he described for n <= 10^5 values and 20s time limit. Doesn't building the heaps already take O(nlogn)? I don't think this is an improvement or is it?

Comment: You could pivot sort and check the number of evens & odds on each side of the pivot is as expected on every step.

Comment: @marca, heaps can be built in O(n).

Comment: @Dave, that could be an idea, but you would need to deal with duplicate values that might end up at either side, and should not give a false negative (or positive, depending on how you define that term).

Comment: And the thing is that I tried to keep the algorithm efficient but the funny thing is that. I did the same algorithm in JS and even in python and it works just fine in the platform, maybe is a problem with dart? or how it reads the inputs?